# Check if an array contains another array swift

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

In my app I am trying to check and see if 2 users already have a conversation created inside of my AWS DynamoDB table and if not a conversation between the users will be created. I use the list query function to check and see if an array of `currentUserSub` and `recieverUserSub` is created but I am getting an error saying

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Conversation.CodingKeys' and '[String]'
```

Conversations has field in its table named members which is an array value of Strings.

Here is my code:

```
    let conversations = Conversation.keys
        let predicate = conversations.members == [currentUserSub, recieverUserSub] // this is where I get the error
        _ = Amplify.API.query(request: .list(Conversation.self, where: predicate)) { event in
            switch event {
            case .success(let result):
                switch result {
                case .success(let convo):
                    print("Successfully retrieved the convo: \(convo)")

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Got failed event with error \(error)")
            }
        }
```

How could I go about fixing this?

I reference this function from the amplify docs https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/ios#list-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`let predicate = conversations.members.contains(currentUserSub) && conversations.members.contains(recieverUserSub)`